# Adding an editable row below parent row

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Company/JQueryDataTableEditableLayout.cshtml";
}

@section head{

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable({
        "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null, {
            tooltip: 'Double-Click'
        }, {
            tooltip: 'Double-Click to select Code'
        }]
    });
    $('#myDataTable tbody td button').live('click', function () {
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        $(myDataTable).dataTable().fnAddData(["test", "test1", "test2", "test3"]);
    });
});
</script>
}

<div id="demo">
    <h1>Basic Example</h1>
    <table id="myDataTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Company name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Town</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @{

                foreach (var item in Model)

            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Address</td>
                    <td>@item.Town</td>
                    <td> <button id= "@item.ID"  name="Split" >SplitLine</button></td>
                </tr>

            }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

I am using datatable editable and I want to add a new editable row below the parent row.

Here is the code I have so far and it is adding the new row towards the end.

Comment: If I would be you, I would use the `contenteditable` attribute on the table. [See example here](http://jfnoel.com/SO/dynamic_table/admin.html).

Comment: newer versions of jQuery should use `.on` rather than the deprecated `.live`

Answer (score 0):

In your function

```
$('#myDataTable tbody td button').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    $(myDataTable).dataTable().fnAddData(["test", "test1", "test2", "test3"]);
});
```

You never use `nTr` and in `$(myDataTable)` the `myDataTable` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: $(myDataTable) is declared below $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: `$('#myDataTable')` is NOT the same thing, and it is NOT declared in the code you provided.

Comment: It is declared towards the end  <table id="myDataTable" class="display">

Comment: That is an element NOT a JavaScript variable.